# Keep row names when using rbind.fill in R

Tags: r, plyr, rbind

Does anyone know how to keep rownames in the `rbind.fill` function.

```
library(plyr)

#creating data
a <- mtcars[ 1:5 , c("mpg","hp","gear") ]
b <- mtcars[ 6:10 , c("mpg","disp","gear") ]

#does not work because there are different colnames
rbind(a,b)

#works but eliminates the rownames
bound <- rbind.fill( a , b )
```

I am setting up a loop where objects will be connected using `rbind.fill`.  Right now I am using the combine function like this:

```
namess <- c( rownames(a) , rownames(b) )
rownames(bound) <- namess
```

I thought that there might be a better way.  Thanks!

Comment: I would consider this a bug. I don't know if `plyr` has a bug report forum/place, but if it does someone should link to it and this should be submitted imo.

Comment: @eddi agreed :)  i have just submitted it on github  https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/156

Comment: Plyr does not support row names. It's a better idea to put them in a variable, and then deal with them explicitly.

Comment: @hadley any reason why `plyr` functions that operate on `data.frame`s shouldn't support row names? This seems like a natural and trivial change to add to `rbind.fill`.

Comment: @eddi My reasoning is above: rownames don't add anything you can't already do. Plus it's not obvious how they work with (e.g.) `ddply`.

Comment: @hadley - I agree that the issue doesn't apply to `ddply`, but it does to `rbind.fill`. Just because *other* functions in `plyr` don't/can't deal with `data.frame` row names, doesn't mean this one shouldn't either.

Comment: @eddi I'd happily accept a patch and test cases

Answer (score 2):

You could try to apply a custom function that performs `rbind.fill` and sets initial rownames automatically like that:

```
# List of sample data
ab.list <- list(a <- mtcars[1:5 , c("mpg","hp","gear")], 
                b <- mtcars[6:10 , c("mpg","disp","gear")])

# Apply custom function (rbind and rownames adjustment) to sample data
do.call(function(...) {

  tmp <- plyr::rbind.fill(...)
  rownames(tmp) <- sapply(ab.list, function(i) {
    rownames(i)
  })

  return(tmp)

}, ab.list)

                   mpg  hp gear  disp
Mazda RX4         21.0 110    4    NA
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0 110    4    NA
Datsun 710        22.8  93    4    NA
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 110    3    NA
Hornet Sportabout 18.7 175    3    NA
Valiant           18.1  NA    3 225.0
Duster 360        14.3  NA    3 360.0
Merc 240D         24.4  NA    4 146.7
Merc 230          22.8  NA    4 140.8
Merc 280          19.2  NA    4 167.6
```

Check out [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799434/rbind-two-data-frame-preserving-row-order-and-row-names) that deals with a similar problem.

Comment: It's probably better to extract the row names first from within the function by parsing the arguments in `...` than reaching back into the parent frame for them.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble coming up with an elegant way of having it handle both passing `ab.list` _and_ `ab.list[[1]], ab.list[[2]]` separately.

Answer (score 1):

Since I posted this question five years ago - a new function became available.  smartbind solves this issue.

```
library( gtools) 

#creating data
a <- mtcars[ 1:5 , c("mpg","hp","gear") ]
b <- mtcars[ 6:10 , c("mpg","disp","gear") ]

smartbind( a , b )
```

Comment: Are you sure? `smartbind` doesn't keep rownames either!

Comment: @TMS - huh, it did 2 years ago.  I removed the check