# Row Binding a Set of Data Sets?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, bind

I have read in a list of data sets and called this n. What I wish to do is take a subset of the data sets from n and row bind them together in R. When I try to go `rbind(n)` this just gives me the data frame of all the names of the data sets instead of actually putting the elements of each data set underneath each other. What I want to do is bind subsets of the data sets that share a common name. For example, 18 of the data sets start with "4." and I want to bind all these together. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Want you want to do is `rbind(n[[1]],n[[2]],...)` which is not the same as `rbind(n)`.

You don't need to write this out, you can use `do.call` to create and execute this `call`

```
 do.call(rbind, n)
```

which will run the command you want. However, this is [notoriously slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290824/1385941)

You can use `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package to do the same thing much faster

```
 library(data.table)

 rbindlist(n)
```

If you only want those elements whose name start with `4`

```
rbindlist(n[grep(names(n), pattern = '^4')])
```

Comment: Awesome thank you that does exactly what I want! Now how can I do this for a subset, say files containing "4." somewhere in their name within n without actually having to go look which numbers in the list those files belong to?

Comment: @user1836894 Are these the names of the elements of the list?

Comment: Yes they are. I have a list of files and those are the names belonging to a subset of the files.

Comment: @user1836894 added an approach, let me know if it isn't suitable.

Comment: +1! @mnel maybe change the pattern from numeric to a valid file name! it looks odd a file name beginning with 4. and you can give the list of names `n[filtred.names]`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you that did what I wanted! I'm sorry to be a bother but is it possible to do this bind with a different number of columns in some of the data sets? For example such as 'rbind.fill' would, but with the 'rbindlist' you suggested?

Comment: I have a `not-optimized` approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15017231/1385941). This will not be as fast as rbindlist.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to aggregate many files, You might need the `rbind.fill` function in plyr package ( i don'konw if there is a data.table equivalent)

```
ll <- list(a=data.frame(x=1,y=2,z=1),
         b= data.frame(x=2,y=3),
         c=data.frame(x=3:4,y=5))

library(plyr)
Reduce(rbind.fill,ll[c('a','b')])   ## subset by list names and 
                                    ## apply recursively using Reduce
  x y  z
1 1 2  1
2 2 3 NA
```

Comment: I don't know of an rbind.fill equivalent, but I implemented something http://stackoverflow.com/a/15017231/1385941