# LIst of lists in R into a data.frame - inconsistent variable names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of lists and I want to convert it into a dataframe. The challenge is that there are missing variables names in lists (not NA's but the variable is missing completely).

To illustrate on example: from

```
my_list <- list() 
my_list[[1]] <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
my_list[[2]] <- list(a = 4, c = 6)
```

I would like to get

```
     a  b c
[1,] 1  2 3
[2,] 4 NA 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
library(reshape2)
as.data.frame(acast(melt(my_list), L1~L2, value.var='value'))
#  a  b c
#1 1  2 3
#2 4 NA 6
```

Or as @David Arenburg suggested a wrapper for `melt/dcast` would be `recast`

```
recast(my_list, L1 ~ L2, value.var = 'value')[, -1]
#  a  b c
#1 1  2 3
#2 4 NA 6
```

Comment: Or maybe `recast(my_list, L1 ~ L2, value.var = 'value')[, -1]`, though the `-1` is ugly probably.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I tried that before, but there is not an option with a `acast` matrix output

Comment: OP explicitly said they want to convert it to a data frame.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, just noticed that.  I was looking at his matrix output

Comment: @akrun You might wish to add your nice suggestion to [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/rbind-different-number-of-columns) which seems like a possible canonical answer for similar questions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please do add all the suggestions here in the link Henrik suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bind_rows` function from the `dplyr` package :

```
my_list <- list() 
my_list[[1]] <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
my_list[[2]] <- list(a = 4, c = 6)
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(my_list, as.data.frame))
```

This outputs:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
  a  b c
1 1  2 3
2 4 NA 6
```

Comment: Or `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(my_list, as.data.frame), fill = TRUE)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg You might wish to add your nice suggestion to [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/rbind-different-number-of-columns) which seems like a possible canonical answer for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, this requires to change the class of the arguments to data.frames:

```
 library(plyr)
 lista <- list(a=1, b=2, c =3)
 listb <- list(a=4, c=6)
 lista <- as.data.frame(lista)
 listb <- as.data.frame(listb)
 my_list <- list(lista, listb)
 my_list <- do.call(rbind.fill, my_list)
 my_list
   a  b c
 1 1  2 3
 2 4 NA 6
```

Comment: BTW, you are not using the example data structure provided by the OP.  If you are creating a new structure, you would use something similar as @Tutuchan's code rather than manually changing/creating.

Comment: This is way to manual. OP already provided the data. All you need to do is just `my_list <- lapply(my_list, as.data.frame) ; do.call(rbind.fill, my_list)`