# How to join 2 dataframes, fill missing row values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1

  ua ub a b c
1 11 12 1 1 0
2 12 13 2 2 2
3 13 14 1 1 1
4 14 15 1 1 1
5 15 16 1 1 1
6 16 17 1 1 1

df2

  ua ub a b c d e f
1 11 12 1 1 0 1 1 1
2 14 15 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 16 17 1 1 1 1 1 1
4 12 13 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I want to join the two dataframes on `ua` and `ub`, and add on the columns in `df2` not in `df1` onto `df1`, and "fill in" the missing rows with a `0`.

This would give:

```
  ua ub a b c d e f
1 11 12 1 1 0 1 1 1
2 12 13 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 13 14 1 1 1 0 0 0
4 14 15 1 1 1 1 1 1
5 15 16 1 1 1 0 0 0
6 16 17 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I can get the column names in `df2` not in `df1` by doing:

```
setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))
```

But I'm a bit stuck on how to then merge / concat the remaining results.

I looked at this q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns) but no luck making it work for me.

In Pandas Python, I could use `merge` combined with `.ffill()` but I'm unsure how to translate this into R. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could use `full_join` from the `dplyr` package. Then you could replace NAs with 0s?

Comment: `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)` then replace `NA` with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use all column names that `df1` and `df2` have in common:

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
ua ub a b c
1 11 12 1 1 0
2 12 13 2 2 2
3 13 14 1 1 1
4 14 15 1 1 1
5 15 16 1 1 1
6 16 17 1 1 1
", header=T)

df2 = read.table(text = "
  ua ub a b c d e f
1 11 12 1 1 0 1 1 1
2 14 15 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 16 17 1 1 1 1 1 1
4 12 13 2 2 2 2 2 2
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by=c("ua", "ub", "a", "b", "c")) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))

#   ua ub a b c d e f
# 1 11 12 1 1 0 1 1 1
# 2 12 13 2 2 2 2 2 2
# 3 13 14 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 4 14 15 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 5 15 16 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 6 16 17 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Another way to do the above without manually specifying the common columns names is this

```
common_names = intersect(names(df1), names(df2))

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by=common_names) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
```

Otherwise, you can remove any columns from `df2` that you don't want to join and have them twice in your final dataset and use `by=c("ua", "ub")` when you join:

```
names_to_use = c("ua", "ub", setdiff(names(df2), names(df1)))
df2_upd = df2[,names_to_use]

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2_upd, by=c("ua", "ub")) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
```

Comment: When I try this on my larger df I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Argument 2 must be type double, not integer.`

Comment: Hmmm. That's because of the different variable types and `coalesce`. I'll update my solution.

Comment: So columns in df1 with the same name as those in df2 had different types even though they had the same name?

Comment: More likely that different columns had different types. `mutate_all` will apply the function to all columns and `coalesce` depends on the column types, when `ifelse` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to retain all cases of `df1` and not `df2`. Below could be used

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2)
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
```

if all cases of `df1` as well as `df2` is required then replace `left_join` with `full join` in above code