# R rbind different sized tables without duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I've been struggling to make this work all day and I can't figure it out. I have two tables x and y that I'd like to combine. The first two columns of y are a subset of x, but y has an extra column. I'd like to combine the two without having duplicates in the first two columns.

x:

```
A    B
------
1    2
3    4
5    6
7    8
9    10
```

y:

```
A    B    C
-------------
1    2    123
3    4    456
9    10   789
```

I'd like my result to be:

```
A    B    C
-------------
1    2    123
3    4    456
5    6    0
7    8    0
9    10   789
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you share your tables in valid R syntax? `dput()` makes this easy, just post `dput(x)` and `dput(y)` in your question. It makes it much easier to demonstrate an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to `merge` the tables?

Comment: Also, please save the RStudio tag for questions where RStudio is part of the problem - for example if you have R code that runs fine in the R command line but doesn't work in RStudio.

Comment: As for a solution, looks like `merge(x, y, all = T)`. You can easily replace the `NA`s with `0`s afterwards.

Comment: Questions similar to this have definitely come up here before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns)).  Not sure if this is an exact duplicate though.

Comment: `dplyr::left_join` also can be used to accomplish it

Comment: For some more information about what I've tried. <br/> `z <- rbind(x, y[, c("A", "B")])`   <br/> `z <- z[!(duplicated(z)|duplicated(z, fromLast = TRUE)),] `  to remove duplicates <br/>  `rbind(z, y, fill=TRUE)`

Comment: This is called **merging** the data. Not rbinding... so you need to use **merge()** as described by @Gregor above.

Comment: @Gregor Wow works like a charm, I can't believe how much time I've put in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a `JOIN` operation. I'd use `dplyr::full_join()`:

```
x <- data.frame('A' = c(1,3,5,7,9), 'B' = c(2,4,6,8,10))
y <- data.frame('A' = c(1,3,9), 'B' = c(2,4,10), 'C' = c(123, 456, 789))
dplyr::full_join(x,y)
# Joining, by = c("A", "B")
  A  B   C
1 1  2 123
2 3  4 456
3 5  6  NA
4 7  8  NA
5 9 10 789
```

`full_join` will keep all columns from both tables, matching on all identical variables (or whatever variables you choose using the `by =` argument). When there are not matching values, it returns `NA`, but you can replace `NA` with `0` if you'd prefer.