# how to rbind list of different lengths in r

Tags: r

I have extracted tables from pdf file with `tabulizer` package. After extracting tables I want to rbind different tables extracted as list with different length.

```
 table1 <- extract_tables("\\AC002_2017.pdf")

 final <- do.call(rbind, table1)
```

But it gives me following error

```
 Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

How can I rbind it?

Format of data is as follows

```
 [[1]]   [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]

 [1,]    20     45     34      34 
 [2,]    23     34     67      43
 [3,]    22     23     42      34
 [4,]    45     44     56      54
 [5,]    12     11     12      14
 [6,]    34     33     45      32
```

Comment: What is the structure of `table1`? What is the structure of the expected output? Since it doesn't seem to be a matrix or dataframe, it isn't clear why `rbibd` is relevant. Did you try `as.list(table1)`?

Comment: Also, if they have different column counts, how do you want them rbound? According to some key, or just fill in NAs to the end?

Comment: Fill NAs to the end

Comment: @JohnColeman Every page is extracted as list,4 pages have 26 rows and 4 pages have 48 rows,that's where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe, try my answer [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns/46635610#46635610).

Comment: I extract the data as `data.frame` and then use `merge(..., all = T, fill = T)` with a `do.call` instead. Give it a shot if `rbind` is troublesome.