# how to write tryCatch() function when extracting data from multiple files?

Tags: r, try-catch

I am currently working on thousands of files (with .MOD extension) where I want to extract specific information from all these files. These information will then be collected into one excel sheet in such a way that each row represents information extracted from one .MOD file. I have managed to do this.

However, there are lets say about 10-20 files (out of the tens of thousands) that do not contain information in the format that I want, and this therefore throws an error. I cannot of course manually keep digging into all the files, or cannot subset them each time to find which of these files is throwing the error. Therefore, I want to include a tryCatch() function, so that the script still continues to run without stopping. For the files that give error, I simply want the values to be replaced by "Error" in those specific cells. Can anyone help me how to do that?

Following is how I want my final excel output to look like:

```
ID  COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6    COL7    COL8
Sample1 9-5-2014    10:42:41    600 1207    3   2   62  30
Sample2 8-1-2013    08:44:50    654 1873    1   7   60  45
Sample3 2-3-2013    14:47:40    767 1645    1   18  66  37
Sample4 8-2-2013    08:50:45    727 1500    1   8   68  45
Sample5 4-1-2013    13:08:49    Error   Error   Error   Error   Error   Error
Sample6 1-2-2013    13:08:47    720 1433    1   16  60  51
Sample7 3-4-2013    13:59:04    610 1343    2   13  66  32
```

Following is my code (along with the error):

```
AR.MOD.files <- list.files(pattern = "AR.MOD|ar.MOD")
    for (fileName in AR.MOD.files) {
    AR.MOD <- read.table(fileName, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
    AR.MOD.subset1 <- AR.MOD[c(1), 3:4]
    names(AR.MOD.subset1) <- c("COL1", "COL2")
    AR.MOD.subset2 <- AR.MOD[c(3), 3:8]
    names(AR.MOD.subset2) <- c("COL3", "COL4", "COL5", "COL6", "COL7", "COL8")
    AR.MOD.final <- merge(AR.MOD.subset1, AR.MOD.subset2)
    ID <- basename(fileName)
    AR.MOD.final <- merge (ID, AR.MOD.final)
    colnames(AR.MOD.final)[colnames(AR.MOD.final)=="x"] <- "ID"
    if(match(fileName,AR.MOD.files)==1){
            output.AR.MOD <- AR.MOD.final
        }else{
            output.AR.MOD <- rbind(output.AR.MOD,AR.MOD.final)}
        }
Error in `[.data.frame`(AR.MOD, c(3), 3:8) : undefined columns selected
    output.AR.MOD$ID <- gsub("AR.MOD", "", paste(output.AR.MOD$ID))
    output.AR.MOD$ID <- gsub("ar.MOD", "", paste(output.AR.MOD$ID))
    print(output.AR.MOD)
```

I here share 2 example files:

```
> AR.MOD <- read.table("Sample1ar.MOD", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
> AR.MOD
    V1 V2        V3       V4   V5    V6   V7    V8
1 Case  1 23-3-2013 14:47:40                      
2  Run NA                                         
3    R  1    767,96  1647,72 1,78 18,88 0,66 37,33

> AR.MOD <- read.table("Sample2AR.MOD", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
> AR.MOD
    V1 V2       V3       V4   V5   V6   V7    V8
1 Case  1 9-5-2014 10:42:41                     
2  Run NA                                       
3    R  1   566,47  1207,22 3,05 2,95 0,62 30,00
```

It works with the above 2 examples. However, if one of the column is missing, lets say in the following, then it throws error.

```
> AR.MOD <- read.table("Sample3AR.MOD", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
> AR.MOD
    V1 V2        V3      V4   V5   V6   V7
1 Case  1 28-1-2013 8:44:50                     
2  Run NA                                       
3    R  1    783,76 1873,70 1,34 7,48 0,60
```

I am at this point not sure which file it is coming from, but I here send you a dummy example in the 3rd sample from above. I am not able to attach files directly here, that is why I read it and send you as an output.

Comment: Where exactly does your error occur? It isn't clear to me at which point the process is producing an error. However ... *strongly* urge you to not use `rbind` iteratively, its performance will scale very poorly, and if you have 10k files, you will know very quickly (and wait a long time). Suggest wrapping this in `lapply` and then do *once*: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_of_frames)`. This might help resolve some of your errant-file problems, too.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about rbind. I will work on that. Regarding the error, it shows exactly after the step where I showed in the code. But it probably comes from here "AR.MOD.subset2 <- AR.MOD[c(3), 3:8]" because in those files with errors, there are no columns from 3:8. Probably 1 or 2 columns in those files are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd echo the `lapply` solution to make the tables in individual list elements and then handle the combination afterwards. Here is an example using the `data.table` package that fills the data with NA's where it can't find it:

```
# # for installing:
# install.packages(data.table)
library(data.table)

# generate tables with uneven columns
set.seed(1)
tables <- lapply(1:10, function(i){
  ncols <- sample(1:5, 1, 1)
  out <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(ncols), nrow=1, ncol=ncols))
})

# you can use rbindlist with fill=TRUE to fill the bad values with NA
output <- as.data.frame(rbindlist(tables, fill=TRUE))
```

EDIT:
I can't be certain this will work off the bat, but give it a try:

```
# # for installing:
# install.packages(data.table)
library(data.table)

# Set this to what you expect max to be 
ncol_total <- 9
tables <- lapply(AR.MOD.files, function(fileName){
  AR.MOD <- read.table(fileName, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
  AR.MOD.subset1 <- AR.MOD[c(1), 3:4]
  names(AR.MOD.subset1) <- c("COL1", "COL2")
  AR.MOD.subset2 <- AR.MOD[c(3), 3:8]
  names(AR.MOD.subset2) <- c("COL3", "COL4", "COL5", "COL6", "COL7", "COL8")
  AR.MOD.final <- merge(AR.MOD.subset1, AR.MOD.subset2)
  ID <- basename(fileName)
  AR.MOD.final <- merge (ID, AR.MOD.final)
  colnames(AR.MOD.final)[colnames(AR.MOD.final)=="x"] <- "ID"

  # add in missing data
  ncol_file <- ncol(AR.MOD.final)
  missing <- ncol_total - ncol_file
  if(missing > 0){
    new_data <- as.data.frame(matrix("Error", nrow=nrow(AR.MOD.final), ncol=missing))
    AR.MOD.final <- cbind(AR.MOD.final, AR.MOD.final)
  }

  AR.MOD.final
})

# this will likely screw up the column names. Its better to know what these
# are and assign after, as long as the tables are all in the same order
output <- as.data.frame(rbindlist(tables, use.names = FALSE))
names(output) <- c("ID", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL5", "COL6", "COL7"
                   "COL8")

# continuing on
output$ID <- gsub("AR.MOD", "", paste(output$ID))
output$ID <- gsub("ar.MOD", "", paste(output$ID))
print(output)
```

Comment: If the user doesn't need `data.table` for other parts, then `rbindlist` can be replaced (with minor nuances) with `do.call(rbind.data.frame, tables)`.

Comment: That errors for me due to the columns not matching. Does it have an argument similar to `fill` in `rbindlist`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns for other alternatives. Edit: its a bit old now, its `dplyr` now not `plyr` for top solution

Comment: @Jonny: Will you be able to implement your code with my full code just so I can try it as it is, rather than making mistakes? Also, is it possible to add something else other than NA (may be "Error")? I do have NAs in the excel file due to other reasons. Thats why I want to separate these with other names in order to know that is due to the error.

Comment: yeah sure, edited my answer. Ah wait, just seen what you mean, ignore my edit

Comment: Ok might work now. I've moved towards adding in the data to each lapply if we can test its missing by checking the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks so much for editing. I just tried the part until AR.MOD.final }) It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Jonny: if you need `fill=` then that sounds like your files are not structured identically. Letin, can you provide two file samples (with a few rows each)? Just something representative for testing.

Comment: @Jonny and r2evans: Really thank you for your efforts. I have edited my question for you to see the files that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach.

```r
writeLines("a,b\n1,2", "Letin_good.csv")
writeLines("", "Letin_bad1.csv")
writeLines("c,d\n3,4", "Letin_bad2.csv")

# myfiles <- list.files(pattern = "Letin.*\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
myfiles <- c("Letin_good.csv", "Letin_good.csv", "Letin_bad1.csv", "Letin_good.csv", "Letin_bad2.csv")

datlist <- lapply(myfiles, function(fn) {
  tryCatch({
    out <- read.csv(fn, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    # do something with the data
    out
  },
    error = function(e) NULL)
})
str(datlist)
# List of 5
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: int 1
#   ..$ b: int 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: int 1
#   ..$ b: int 2
#  $ : NULL
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: int 1
#   ..$ b: int 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ c: int 3
#   ..$ d: int 4
```

At this point, the third element is clearly wrong (`read.csv` failed) and the fifth element is incorrect (wrong headers). We can generate a filter of sorts that returns `TRUE` if all "conditions" are met (e.g., all required names present):

```r
gooddatlist <- Filter(function(x) {
  all(
    c("a", "b") %in% names(x)
    # other tests
  )
}, datlist)
str(gooddatlist)
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: num 12
#   ..$ b: int 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: num 12
#   ..$ b: int 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ a: num 12
#   ..$ b: int 2

alldat <- do.call(rbind, gooddatlist)
```