# How to rbind two dataframes in R when one has more columns than the other

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I want to merge three dataframes together, appending them as rows to the bottom of the previous, but I want their columns to match. Each dataframe has a different number of columns, but they share column names. EX:

```
Dataframe A                  Dataframe B                     Dataframe C
A B Y Z                      A B C X Y Z                     A B C D W X Y Z
# # # #                      # # # # # #                     # # # # # # # #
```

In the end, I want them to look like:

```
Dataframe_Final
A B C D W X Y Z
# #         # #
# # #     # # #
# # # # # # # #
```

How can I merge these dataframes together in this way? Again, there's no ID for the rows that is unique (ascending, etc) across the dataframes.
Thanks!

Comment: See the `bind_rows()` function from the dplyr package.

Comment: Tell me more on how `D` and `W` columns comes about?

Comment: Provide `Minimum Working Example (MWE)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two data frames by rows (rbind) when they have different sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns)

Answer (score 1):

A base R option might be `Reduce` + `merge`

```
out <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all = TRUE),list(dfA,dfB,dfC))
out <- out[order(names(out))]
```

which gives

```
  A B  C  D  W  X Y Z
1 1 2 NA NA NA NA 3 4
2 1 2  3 NA NA  4 5 6
3 1 2  3  4  5  6 7 8
```

**Dummy Data**

```
dfA <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, Y = 3, Z = 4)
dfB <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, X = 4, Y = 5, Z = 6)
dfC <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, W = 5, X = 6, Y = 7, Z = 8)
```