# In R: appending using gtools

Tags: r

I have used the code

```
library(gtools)
subset4 <- smartbind(subset1, subset2, subset3)
```

and am trying to append three datasets that have variables with the same name but it turns out like this:[image: output of appending with smartbind]

I have done it in the same way before and it has worked, so I do not understand what has gone wrong here.. Anyone keen to help me out? Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide example data, `dput(head(subset1))`,  `dput(head(subset2))`, and `dput(head(subset3))`

Comment: Did you try other package solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3402371/680068

Comment: @zx8754 I edited the post, is that what you wanted?

Comment: but a solution from the link you gave worked, thanks!

Comment: Happy linked post worked for you, I closed as duplicate. Your example input does work with `gtools::smartbind(subset1, subset2, subset3)`, too.

Comment: ok great, thanks for checking!