# Use dplyr package to merge two dataframes into one but add values to specific columns of the merged dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the 2 datasets below:

original_1

```
id type   city   state   zip  
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
 1     1 type1  city1  state1  zip1 
 2     2 type2  city2  state2  zip2 
 3     3 type3  city3  state3  zip3 
 4     4 type4  city4  state4  zip4 
 5     5 type5  city5  state5  zip5 
 6     6 type6  city6  state6  zip6 
 7     7 type7  city7  state7  zip7 
 8     8 type8  city8  state8  zip8 
 9     9 type9  city9  state9  zip9 
10    10 type10 city10 state10 zip10
11    11 type11 city11 state11 zip11
```

original2

```
id1 type1  city1  state1  zip1  data  data_1            data_2           
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>             <chr>            
 1    12 type12 city12 state12 zip12 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 2    13 type13 city13 state13 zip13 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 3    14 type14 city14 state14 zip14 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 4    15 type15 city15 state15 zip15 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 5    16 type16 city16 state16 zip16 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 6    17 type17 city17 state17 zip17 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 7    18 type18 city18 state18 zip18 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 8    19 type19 city19 state19 zip19 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 9    20 type20 city20 state20 zip20 data1 Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
10    NA NA     NA     NA      NA    NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
11    NA NA     NA     NA      NA    data2 Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
```

and I want to bind them in a way that the second dataset will be the continuation of the first dataset. And then I want to fill the `NAs` in the columns `data1` `data2` with the values in that came from the second dataset using the dplyr package. I also want to remove the `type` column. The values of column `data` which exists in `original2` should be moved to their initial row postions `9` and `11` and any rows that do not contain a value for `id` must be removed.

```
id city   state   data  data_1            data_2           
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>             <chr>            
 1     1 city1  state1  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 2     2 city2  state2  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 3     3 city3  state3  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 4     4 city4  state4  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 5     5 city5  state5  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 6     6 city6  state6  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 7     7 city7  state7  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 8     8 city8  state8  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 9     9 city9  state9  data1 Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
10    10 city10 state10 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
11    11 city11 state11 data2 Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
12    12 city12 state12 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
13    13 city13 state13 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
14    14 city14 state14 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
15    15 city15 state15 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
16    16 city16 state16 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
17    17 city17 state17 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
18    18 city18 state18 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
19    19 city19 state19 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
20    20 city20 state20 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
```

datasets

```
original_1<-structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), type = c("type1", 
"type2", "type3", "type4", "type5", "type6", "type7", "type8", 
"type9", "type10", "type11"), city = c("city1", "city2", "city3", 
"city4", "city5", "city6", "city7", "city8", "city9", "city10", 
"city11"), state = c("state1", "state2", "state3", "state4", 
"state5", "state6", "state7", "state8", "state9", "state10", 
"state11"), zip = c("zip1", "zip2", "zip3", "zip4", "zip5", "zip6", 
"zip7", "zip8", "zip9", "zip10", "zip11")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L))



original2<- structure(list(id1 = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, NA, 
NA), type1 = c("type12", "type13", "type14", "type15", "type16", 
"type17", "type18", "type19", "type20", NA, NA), city1 = c("city12", 
"city13", "city14", "city15", "city16", "city17", "city18", "city19", 
"city20", NA, NA), state1 = c("state12", "state13", "state14", 
"state15", "state16", "state17", "state18", "state19", "state20", 
NA, NA), zip1 = c("zip12", "zip13", "zip14", "zip15", "zip16", 
"zip17", "zip18", "zip19", "zip20", NA, NA), data = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "data1", NA, "data2"), data_1 = c("Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data"), data_2 = c("Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", 
"Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data", "Non_changing_data"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Maybe you want rbind with fill missing columns? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3402371/680068 Also, I don't understand how the data_1 and data_2 columns are getting filled for original1 dataset after "unite"?

Comment: it does not work. data1 and data2 dont exist in the original_1 and when merged they should get filled with "Non_changing_data" that exists in data1 data2 of original2

Comment: Yes, they do not exist, but if you try the solutions from linked post, you will they get populated with NAs for missing columns.

Comment: Once we have rbind them we can fill in the NAs with any value we want.

Comment: I get 13 variables instead of the reuested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the result that you are looking for?

You can use `dplyr::bind_rows` in combination with `tidyr::fill` to get it. The column names need some cleaning up though.

```
library(dplyr)

# Clean up column names to add second dataset to the first using rename() to remove the numbers
original2 %>% 
  rename(id = id1,
         type = type1,
         city = city1,
         state = state1, 
         zip = zip1) %>% 
  # Add dataset 1 and cleaned up dataset 2 together
  bind_rows(original_1, .) %>% 
  # Fill NAs with data from dataset 2 using tidyr::fill()
  tidyr::fill(data_1, .direction = "up") %>% 
  tidyr::fill(data_2, .direction = "up") %>% 
  # Remove "type" column
  select(-type) %>% 
  # Artificially replace values "data1" and "data2" in "data" to row 9 and 11 respectively
  mutate(data = case_when(row_number() == 9 ~ "data1",
                          row_number() == 11 ~ "data2",
                          TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  # Remove rows that do not contain a value for "id"
  filter(! is.na(id))

# A tibble: 20 x 7
      id city   state   zip   data  data_1            data_2           
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>             <chr>            
 1     1 city1  state1  zip1  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 2     2 city2  state2  zip2  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 3     3 city3  state3  zip3  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 4     4 city4  state4  zip4  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 5     5 city5  state5  zip5  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 6     6 city6  state6  zip6  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 7     7 city7  state7  zip7  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 8     8 city8  state8  zip8  NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
 9     9 city9  state9  zip9  data1 Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
10    10 city10 state10 zip10 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
11    11 city11 state11 zip11 data2 Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
12    12 city12 state12 zip12 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
13    13 city13 state13 zip13 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
14    14 city14 state14 zip14 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
15    15 city15 state15 zip15 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
16    16 city16 state16 zip16 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
17    17 city17 state17 zip17 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
18    18 city18 state18 zip18 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
19    19 city19 state19 zip19 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
20    20 city20 state20 zip20 NA    Non_changing_data Non_changing_data
```

Comment: great.can you also remove the column type from the new one?

Comment: yes, add `%>% select(-type)` to the code. I edited the original answer to fit your second question.

Comment: Please mark my post as the correct answer to your question if this works for you.

Comment: sure I will but I noticed that data1 and data2 should be in lines 9 and 11 and not 20 22

Comment: Can you explain the condition that it is based on, then I can add it to the code. It is not included in your original question.

Comment: you can say that the values of column data which exists in original2 should remain in their initial row postions 9 and 11

Comment: I fixed your issue artificially, although I would not recommend manipulating the data this way.

Answer (score 0):

Does the fucntion full_join answer your question ?

```
test <- full_join(original_1, original2, by = c("id" = "id1",
                                                "type" = "type1",
                                                "city" = "city1",
                                                "state" = "state1",
                                                "zip" = "zip1"))
```

Comment: no data1 and data2 stil have NAs in first 11 rows

Comment: In this case you want to create data, because your first table do not state the value of data_1 and data_2, use "mutate" function.