# How to append dataframes without losing/merging any data in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I'm relatively new to R so please accept my apologies if this seems obvious/silly question- I have tried googling to no avail.

I have two dataframes that I would like to append without merging or losing any data. I hope the below explains what I mean.

I've tried rbind, cbind, merge, but none seem to work in the way I need. I wondered if anyone had any tips?

[image: Example]

Comment: Use `dplyr::bind_rows`, or `data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the tag information about asking questions: " Please use minimal reproducible example(s) others can run using copy & paste. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library(). Don't embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead. " Please do not post images of data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two data frames by rows (rbind) when they have different sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is using the `rbind.fill` from `plyr` function like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  Value1 = c(1,2,3),
                  Value4 = c(7,3,5))

df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  Value1 = c(1,2,3,4),
                  Value2 = c(5,6,1,7))

library(plyr)
rbind.fill(df2,df1)
```

Output:

```
 Name Value1 Value2 Value4
1    A      1      5     NA
2    B      2      6     NA
3    C      3      1     NA
4    D      4      7     NA
5    A      1     NA      7
6    B      2     NA      3
7    C      3     NA      5
```

`bind_rows` from `dplyr` option like @Maël mentioned in comments:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df2,df1)
```

Output:

```
  Name Value1 Value2 Value4
1    A      1      5     NA
2    B      2      6     NA
3    C      3      1     NA
4    D      4      7     NA
5    A      1     NA      7
6    B      2     NA      3
7    C      3     NA      5
```

Comment: `plyr` is not maintained anymore. I'd not encourage its use.

Comment: @Maël, That is true. I mentioned your option!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist`:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)
data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = T)
```