# Combine elements of columns with same name in different Datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two df

df_1

| X | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D |
| E | E | F | G |
| H | I | J | L |

and another, df_2

| X | X4 | X5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Z | Y | W |
| P | O | S |

I would like to merge both by column name and integrate the elements

| X | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | Y | W |
| E | E | F | G | O | S |
| H | I | J | L | NA | NA |
| Z | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| P | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

Answer (score 5):

In `dplyr`, you can use `bind_rows` and then `order` NAs and non-NAs:

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_1, df_2) |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x[order(is.na(.x))]))

#  X   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
#1 A    B    C    D    Y    W
#2 E    E    F    G    O    S
#3 H    I    J    L <NA> <NA>
#4 Z <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#5 P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

With base R you can first [bind rows with different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns) and then move NA values to the end

```
mismatch_rbind <- function(a, b) {
  a[setdiff(names(b), names(a))] <- NA
  b[setdiff(names(a), names(b))] <- NA
  rbind(a, b)
}
na_last <- function(x) {
  r <- x[!is.na(x)]
  length(r) <- length(x)
  r
}

out <- mismatch_rbind(df_1, df_2)
out[] <- lapply(out, na_last)
out
#   X   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
# 1 A    B    C    D    Y    W
# 2 E    E    F    G    O    S
# 3 H    I    J    L <NA> <NA>
# 4 Z <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 5 P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R solution: iterate over all column names to make a list of combined columns; pad with `NA`s to the same length; and coerce back to a dataframe.

```
new_cols <- union(names(df_1), names(df_2)) |>
  setNames(nm = _) |>
  lapply(\(x) c(df_1[[x]], df_2[[x]]))

max_len <- max(sapply(new_cols, length))

new_cols |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    length(x) <- max_len
    x
  }) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

```
  X   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1 A    B    C    D    Y    W
2 E    E    F    G    O    S
3 H    I    J    L <NA> <NA>
4 Z <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5 P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

**solution in data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df_1)
setDT(df_2)

rbindlist(list(df_1, df_2), fill = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, \(x) na.omit(x)[1:.N])]
```

**results**

```
   X   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1: A    B    C    D    Y    W
2: E    E    F    G    O    S
3: H    I    J    L <NA> <NA>
4: Z <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5: P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```