# R: Combining Data Frames With Different Column Names and Numbers of COlumns

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am starting with these 3 data frames - **these frames have different numbers of columns and different column names**:

```
df_1 = data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), col2 = c(2,4,6), col3 = c(5, "B", "F"))
df_2 = data.frame(col4 = c(5,6,7), col5 = c("A", "D", "Z"))
df_3 = data.frame(col6 = c("dog", "cat"), col7 = c("bear", "wolf"), col8 = c("lion", "tiger"), col9 = c("horse", "pig"), col10 = c("shark", "whale"))
```

**My Question: Using these 3 data frames, I am trying to get the following output ("final") where columns from 3 data frames are stacked on top of each other based on their positions :**

```
 final
  new_col_1 new_col_2 new_col_3 new_col_4 new_col_5 new_col_6
1         A         2         5      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
2         B         4         B      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
3         C         6         F      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
4         5         A      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
5         6         D      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
6         7         Z      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
7       dog      bear      <NA>      lion     horse     shark
8       cat      wolf      <NA>     tiger       pig     whale
```

I tried to use the advice from this question here ([Combine two data frames by rows (rbind) when they have different sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns)) to solve my problem :

```
library(gtools)
smartbind(df_1, df_2, df_3)

    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7  col8  col9 col10
1:1    A    2    5   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1:2    B    4    B   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1:3    C    6    F   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2:1 <NA>   NA <NA>    5    A <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2:2 <NA>   NA <NA>    6    D <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2:3 <NA>   NA <NA>    7    Z <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3:1 <NA>   NA <NA>   NA <NA>  dog bear  lion horse shark
3:2 <NA>   NA <NA>   NA <NA>  cat wolf tiger   pig whale
```

**However, this code is not giving me the desired results - can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?**

Thanks!

Comment: how do you mean "based on their positions"? Your addition of `df_3`, for instance, is inconsistent. If you go by "n-th column" (discarding the names), then the last values of `new_col_3` should never be `NA`; if you mean by column name, then ... the actual output where everything is a new column is correct, predictable, and justifiable.

Comment: @r2evans: thank you for pointing this out ... i will fix my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The names are different. Easily remedied, since you don't care about any of the original column names.
2. The column classes are different. Easily remedied, we will convert everything to `character`. I don't think this is fully always desired, you can always use `type.convert(., as.is=TRUE)` as needed.

With this, we can use either `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` to combine them.

```r
frames <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3)
frames2 <- lapply(frames, function(z) {
  z <- setNames(z, paste0("new_col_", seq_along(z)))
  z[] <- lapply(z, as.character)
  z
})
out <- bind_rows(frames2)
out
#   new_col_1 new_col_2 new_col_3 new_col_4 new_col_5
# 1         A         2         5      <NA>      <NA>
# 2         B         4         B      <NA>      <NA>
# 3         C         6         F      <NA>      <NA>
# 4         5         A      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 5         6         D      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 6         7         Z      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 7       dog      bear      lion     horse     shark
# 8       cat      wolf     tiger       pig     whale

### similarly
out <- rbindlist(frames2, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

If you want whatever might be "number-like" to return to this number-like format (will do nothing with *this* data), you can run:

```r
out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: @ R2evans: thank you so much for your answer! I am working on a follow-up question here - can you please take a look at if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175678/r-combining-data-frames-with-different-column-names-and-numbers-of-columns thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just as others have said, you need to standardize the column names and data types. One restriction of a data frame is that every element of a column must be the same data type. Here's a slightly different solution if you prefer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(list(df_1,df_2,df_3),
        ~ {
          
          setNames(.,paste0("new_col_",1:ncol(.))) %>%
            mutate(across(everything(),as.character))
          
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the table in the order that you firstly specified, then it is a matter of specifying the column names accordingly - I do not understand why each column is being given a separate name when you wish to have several values under the same column.

```
df_1 = data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), col2 = c(2,4,6), col3 = c(5, "B", "F"))
df_2 = data.frame(col1 = c(5,6,7), col2 = c("A", "D", "Z"))
df_3 = data.frame(col1 = c("dog", "cat"), col2 = c("bear", "wolf"), col4 = c("lion", "tiger"), col5 = c("horse", "pig"), col6 = c("shark", "whale"))

library(gtools)
smartbind(df_1, df_2, df_3)
```

The columns are named in accordance to the "positions" that you would like each value to appear in, and running the above produces your desired result:

```
    col1 col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
1:1    A    2    5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1:2    B    4    B  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1:3    C    6    F  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2:1    5    A <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2:2    6    D <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2:3    7    Z <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3:1  dog bear <NA>  lion horse shark
3:2  cat wolf <NA> tiger   pig whale
```